# Variable attributes disapearing when put inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Probably a simple question but I can't seem to find the answer. I am dynamically creating a page where I can share twitter links.

```
 var twitter = document.createElement('a');
 twitter.setAttribute('href', 'http://twitter.com/share');
 twitter.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button twitter-tweet');
 twitter.setAttribute('data-text', 'I liked this image');
 etc..
```

I then append it to the div I want such as

```
   $('#doc').append('<img(miscellaneous HTML)>'+twitter)
```

What I have above works but for CSS formatting purposes I want the image with the twitter share button to be a sub-block. So I create something like this

```
  $('#doc').append('<div id="innerblock'+i+'"><img(miscellaneous HTML)>'+twitter+'</div>)
```

But when I do this it seems all the attributes of the twitter var are lost, only printing http: // twitter.com/share on the page instead of the button.

I feel it's probably a basic concept I am forgetting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are tring to concatenate a DOM object and a String via this code

```
 $('#doc').append('<div id="innerblock'+i+'"><img(miscellaneous HTML)>'+twitter+'</div>)
```

This twitter variable contains a DOM object and the rest of the append block is String.

Try this:

```
var div = $('<div id="innerblock'+i+'"><img(miscellaneous HTML)></div>').append(twitter);
$('#doc').append(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is instead of appending the HTML instead you can create the innerblock div and the img tags using document.createElement and append the twitter to the img and the img to the div before appending it all to #doc

Answer (score 0):

You can not concatenate a sting and a DOM node.

```
var div = $("<div id="innerblock'+i+'">").append("<img />").append(twitter);
```

or

```
var div = $("<div/>", {id : "innerblock" + i).append("<img />").append(twitter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting `.outerHTML` `String` of `twitter` for `DOM` element `Object` `twitter` ; also adding closing sing quote `'` at end of string parameter provided to `.append()`

```js
var twitter = document.createElement('a');
 twitter.setAttribute('href', 'http://twitter.com/share');
 twitter.setAttribute('class', 'twitter-share-button twitter-tweet');
 twitter.setAttribute('data-text', 'I liked this image');
var i = 0;
  $('#doc').append('<div id="innerblock'+i+'"><img />'+twitter.outerHTML+'link</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="doc"></div>
```